# Android database query get nullPointer

Tags: android, sql, database, null

I have problem with querying database. (sqlitedb)

I want to query database for 2 selections, when I query for first row everything is ok, but when i want to query for second row, i get null pointer.

Look at my code:

```
public AbsenceData getAbsence( int _subjectId, long date ) {
    AbsenceData absence = null;
    Cursor cursor = null;
            cursor = mDb.query(
            ABSENCES_TABLE_NAME, 
            new String[] { ABSENCE_TYPE, ABSENCE_NOTE }, 
            SUBJECT_ID + "=?" + " AND " + ABSENCE_DATE + "=?", 
            new String[] { String.valueOf( _subjectId), String.valueOf( date ) },
            null, null, null
            );

    if( cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
        absence = new AbsenceData( 0, 0, 0l,cursor.getInt( 0 ), cursor.getString( 1 ));
    }
    return absence;
}
```

I have 2 arguments: subjectId, and date, 
Eg. I query for subjectId = 1, date = today - >> i get wanted data,
but when I query for subjectId = 1, date = tomorrow - >> nullpointer,

And what's more in database i can see tomorrow date, so it should give me wanted data but it doesn't...

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

> but when i want to query for second row, i get null pointer

I suggest you to use correct loop if you are assuming that there can be more than one row:

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
   do {
      Absence a = new Absence();
      a.setName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
      ...

   } while (c.moveToNext());
}
```

Especially in your case your **`NPE`** is thrown because if you pass tomorrow date, your Cursor is **empty** and your condition is not applied so your Absence is assigned to **`NULL`** and returned in this state.

if you want to fix it you need to initialise your object like this:

```
AbsenceData absence = new AbsenceDate();
```

**Note:** You need to add default constructor if you created only parametric.